# Change application name through ant script in android

Tags: android, xml, regex, ant, build.xml

I am trying to change an application name on compilation through an ant script(which is in the build.xml). Application name is stored in strings.xml. Following is the piece of code,

```
<target name="changeName">
        <property
            name="applicationName"
            value="30004" />
        <replaceregexp
            file="C:\Users\<user-name>\git\appname\res\values\strings.xml"
            match='&lt;string name="app_name"&lt;test&lt;/string&lt;'
            replace="\1${applicationName}\2"
            byline="true"/>         

    </target>
```

But it doesnt change the name in strings.xml. Can someone please correct me on what I am doing wrong? Also please let me know how I can achieve similar operation through relative paths.

Thanks

**Edit:**
Following is the xml that needs to be changed through the above mentioned ant script

```
<string name="app_name">Test Application</string>
```

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the file you're trying to modify?  It looks like you have too many `&lt;`s in that regex pattern and not enough `&gt;`s.  Also, you're replacement uses \1 and \2 but your pattern doesn't contain any capturing groups.

Comment: Sure let me share that with you. and I dont know what \1 and \2 means cause I copied that. If you could please shed some light on it so that I better understand the situation here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following replacement will change the "app-name" attribute for any `<string>` element that contains this attribute:

```
<replaceregexp
    file="C:\Users\<user-name>\git\appname\res\values\strings.xml"
    match="&lt;string name=&quot;.+&quot;"
    replace="&lt;string name=&quot;${applicationName}&quot;"
/>
```

To save yourself from escape code hell, you might want to set some properties using CDATA before running the replacement.  This way you can clearly see the regex patterns:

```
<property name="regex.match"><![CDATA[<string name=".+"]]></property>
<property name="regex.replace"><![CDATA[<string name="${applicationName}"]]></property>
<replaceregexp
    file="C:\Users\<user-name>\git\appname\res\values\strings.xml"
    match="${regex.match}"
    replace="${regex.replace}"
/>
```

Comment: Thank You. I had to change few things in your solution and it worked. Instead of changing a value of name="" I wanted to change the value of name="">app_name</string>

Comment: @Ahmed: Please post your solution which you got after modifying this answer.

Comment: Its been more than a year now. What is the issue you are getting?